# how to optimize UPDATE query for better MySQL performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have 2 tables in mySQL db...
they are very large.. its about 1 million now and soon to be 5 million or so

one is jobseeker
other is joomla users table

I want to copy or insert IDs into the jobseeker table where the email column of both matches..

i.e. jobseeker email = jos users  email.

I used below query but it takes too much time and puts heavy load on mysql server ....the queries gets stuck and i always end-up restarting mysql ...

```
UPDATE  `jos_jbjobs_jobseeker` 
SET user_id =   ( SELECT jos_users.id
FROM jos_users
WHERE jos_users.email =  jos_jbjobs_jobseeker.email)
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT jos_users.id
    FROM jos_users
    WHERE jos_users.email =  jos_jbjobs_jobseeker.email);
```

how can I optimize above query to achieve better performance. Also, I would be interested if it can be executed in batches i.e 20000 or 40000 records at time.

Please advise

Comment: Please try to EXPLAIN your SQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html and post the result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
    jos_jbjobs_jobseeker a
    INNER JOIN jos_users b ON a.email = b.email
SET
    a.user_id = b.id
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this simple query?

```
UPDATE jos_jbjobs_jobseeker jjj
JOIN jos_users ju
  ON jjj.email = ju.email
SET jjj.user_id = ju.id;
```

Comment: My answer is exactly the same as above. I just posted it a little later.

Comment: @sony_CO: This answer is the same. Just different aliases.